# Шифрование файлов в windows

Tags: c++, драйвер

**Задание звучит следующим образом:**

> Необходимо реализовать программное средство, которое осуществляет
>   шифрование файлов в заданной директории. Файлы в зашифрованном
>   состоянии должны находиться на жестком диске, а при обращении к ним
>   сторонних программ (notepad, Total Commander, Visual Studio, и т.д.)
>   должна выполняться проверка доступности файла для данной программы.
>   Если программа имеет разрешение на просмотр файла – то произвести
>   расшифровку файла и передать открытое содержимое вызывающей программе;
>   если программа не имеет разрешения – то передать зашифрованное
>   содержимое файла. При добавлении файла в директорию автоматически
>   должно производиться его шифрование.
>
> Программное средство должно быть реализовано в виде драйвера,
>   функционирующий в режиме ядра. Программное средство должно
>   функционировать на 64-разрядной версии операционной системы Microsoft
>   Windows 10. Имя и путь к директории задается на ваш выбор в коде
>   драйвера. Список программ, имеющих разрешение на доступ к файлам,
>   задается на ваш выбор.

Кто может подсказать каким образом это можно реализовать? Что нужно знать для этого? Что почитать?

Сам лично я никогда не писал драйвера, и понятия не имею с чего начать.

Comment: Что это за задание такое?

Comment: Можно поискать кого-нибудь, кто делает курсовые для универа по драйверам(специальности, которые выпускают программистов), может он сделает задание и заодно пояснения добавит.

Comment: Я видел уже это задание как тестовое. А так задание на курсовую тянет. Так что без знаний не стоит его решать.

Comment: Начинать надо с изучения DDK и примеров. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/

Answer (score 0):

Я писал такую программу под Windows 95 на C++. Читать и знать надо очень много. Во-первых, нужно DDK, во-вторых, они меняются под каждую версию ОС, и программу приходится переписывать (во всяком случае, тогда пришлось переписывать под Windows XP), в-третьих, не знаю как сейчас, но тогда DDK не содержал подобных примеров, это издавалось отдельно с запретом поставки к нам, и пришлось нужное украсть, благо я работал в ФАПСИ.
Так что начните со скачивания DDK, и попробуйте там найти подходящий пример. Если хотите, выложу наш код драйвера под Windows 95.

Comment: Было бы интересно глянуть

Comment: Сейчас Этот в ремонте, а код только на нём найти можно. На днях выложу.

Comment: Вот (http://amsawa.narod.ru/data/TIGR.src.rar) полный код программы шифратора-дешифратора тигр, он уже под NT. Вас заинтересует в первую очередь текст sys-драйвера кодера папок, он в поддиректории PATH. Как видите, он уже на си, а не ассемблере, как под виндоуз 95. Вам последний нужен? Могу попробовать поискать в свои аривах.

Answer (score -2):

Вот что нужно знать в первую очередь, а раньше было "труднодоступно", чтобы писать драйверы уровня кернеля ноль для работы с файловой системой:

```
//
// undocumented ntoskrnl variable
//
extern PSHORT           NtBuildNumber;

//
// NT Final Build number
//
#define NT4FINAL     1381

typedef struct _FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION {
    BOOLEAN          ReplaceIfExists;
    HANDLE           RootDirectory;
    ULONG            FileNameLength;
    WCHAR            FileName[1];
} FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION, *PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _FILE_NAME_INFORMATION {
    ULONG            FileNameLength;
    WCHAR            FileName[1];
} FILE_NAME_INFORMATION, *PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION;

// Using NTREGMON-type "hooking" on ZwCreateFile;
// ObReferenceObjectByHandle, System WORKITEMS;
// ObOpenObjectByPointer and ZwReadFile I finally have a solution that
// appears stable.

NTKERNELAPI
NTSTATUS
ObOpenObjectByPointer(
    IN PVOID Object,
    IN ULONG HandleAttributes,
    IN PACCESS_STATE PassedAccessState OPTIONAL,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess OPTIONAL,
    IN POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType OPTIONAL,
    IN KPROCESSOR_MODE AccessMode,
    OUT PHANDLE Handle
    );


// There are two steps in getting the threads context. First you 
// must get a handle to the thread via PsGetCurrentThread() or 
// KeGetCurrentThread(). After you get the handle to the thread, 
// you must call the following function:

NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ZwGetContextThread 
(
    IN HANDLE ThreadHandle,
    IN OUT PCONTEXT ThreadContext
);

// Remember, when creating the thread, you must specify an access 
// type of THREAD_GET_CONTEXT in order to read the context information 
// from the thread.

NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS 
NTAPI
ZwOpenFile( OUT PHANDLE FileHandle,
            IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
            IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
            IN PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
            IN ULONG ShareAccess,
            IN ULONG CreateOptions );

NTSYSAPI
VOID
NTAPI
HalDisplayString( PCHAR String );


NTKERNELAPI
NTSTATUS
IoQueryFileInformation(
    IN PFILE_OBJECT FileObject,
    IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass,
    IN ULONG Length,
    OUT PVOID FileInformation,
    OUT PULONG ReturnedLength
    );


NTSYSAPI // preliminary guess
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile(
    IN HANDLE FileHandle,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    OUT PVOID FsInformation,
    IN ULONG Length,
    IN FS_INFORMATION_CLASS FsInformationClass
    );


NTKERNELAPI // preliminary guess
NTSTATUS
IoQueryFileVolumeInformation(
    IN PFILE_OBJECT FileObject,
    IN FS_INFORMATION_CLASS FsInformationClass,
    IN ULONG Length,
    OUT PVOID FsInformation,
    OUT PULONG ReturnedLength
    );


NTSTATUS
ZwOpenDirectoryObject( OUT PHANDLE DirectoryHandle,
                       IN ULONG DesiredAccess,
                       IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes ); 

NTSTATUS
ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject( OUT PHANDLE SymbolicLinkHandle,
                          IN ULONG DesiredAccess,
                          IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes ); 


NTSTATUS
ZwQuerySymbolicLinkObject( IN HANDLE SymbolicLinkHandle,
                           OUT PUNICODE_STRING ReturnedString,
                           OUT PULONG ReturnedLength ); 

NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS 
NTAPI
ZwCreateSection( OUT PHANDLE SectionHandle,
                 IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
                 IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,   // Optional
                 IN PLARGE_INTEGER MaximumSize,            // Optional
                 IN ULONG SectionPageProtection,
                 IN ULONG AllocationAttributes,
                 IN HANDLE FileHandle );                   // Optional

//
// Parameters:
// SectionHandle   if routine succeeds, you get back a section handle 
//                 in this argument. If you want to use the section
//                 object in the context of some other process, use the
//                 ObReferenceObjectByHandle() and ObOpenObjectByPointer() 
//                 combination to do so ...
//
// DesiredAccess   set this to one of SECTION_MAP_EXECUTE, ...MAP_READ, or
//                 ..._MAP_WRITE 
//
// ObjectAttributes - NULL, or use 
//                 InitializeObjectAttributes() macro to initialize this. 
//                 Use this to create a named section object if you wish 
//                 to share it with user mode process.
//
// MaximumSize     Must be non-NULL for a page-file backed section. If value
//                 specified for a mapped file and the file is not large enough, 
//                 file will be extended. NOTE: this is a POINTER to a large int.
//
// SectionPageProtection  use from PAGE_READONLY, READWRITE, ...WRITEONLY, 
//                 and/or WRITECOPY.
//
// AllocationAttributes  use SEC_IMAGE (executable only), SEC_FILE (for
//                 mapping in a data file), SEC_RESERVE, SEC_COMMIT. 
//                 NOTE: These defines are ONLY in the "winnt.h" file as part 
//                 of the SDK!!!
//
// FileHandle      optional, BUT you must supply if you wish to map in a data
//                 file. Else VMM will create a section object backed by a 
//                 page file.
//

//
// CcCanIWrite()
//

BOOLEAN
CcCanIWrite (
        IN PFILE_OBJECT FileObject,
        IN ULONG                        BytesToWrite,
        IN BOOLEAN                      Wait,
        IN BOOLEAN                      Retrying
);

//
// Resource Acquisition Constraints:
//
// If Wait is TRUE, the file system should ensure that no resources 
// have been acquired. Else, the caller can choose the have the FCB 
// resources unowned, acquired shared or exclusively.
//
// Parameters:
//
// FileObject      Pointer to the file object structure representing 
//                 the open operation performed by the thread.
//
// BytesToWrite    Number of bytes to be modified.
//
// Wait            This argument is used by the Cache Manager to determine 
//                 whether the caller is prepared to wait in the routine 
//                 until it is acceptable for the caller to be allowed 
//                 to perform the write operation.
//
// Retrying        The file system may have to keep requesting permission 
//                 to proceed with a write operation (if Wait is supplied 
//                 as FALSE), until it is allowed to do so. This argument 
//                 allows the file system to notify the Cache Manager 
//                 whether it had previously requested permission for the 
//                 same write request (or if the current instance was the 
//                 first time permission was being requested for the specific 
//                 write operation).
//
// Functionality Provided:
//
// This routine is part of a group of routines that allow the file system 
// to defer executing a write request until it is appropriate to do so. 
// A number of reasons may make executing a write operation immediately, 
// unattractive. They include the following:
//
//  - The file system may wish to restrict the number of dirty pages 
// outstanding per file stream at any given instance in time. This allows 
// the file system to ensure that cached data for other file streams does 
// not get discarded to make space for data belonging to a single file stream. 
// Such a situation may arise if some process kept modifying data for a 
// specific file stream at a very fast rate.
//
// - The Cache Manager tries to keep the total number of modified pages 
// for all files that have their data cached. within a certain limit. 
// This helps ensure that sufficient number of free pages are available 
// for other purposes including memory for loading executable files, 
// memory-mapped files, and memory for other system components.
//
// - The Virtual Memory Manager sets certain limits on the maximum number 
// of dirty pages within the system (based upon the total amount of physical 
// memory present on the system). If the write operation causes the limit 
// to be exceeded, the VMM would prefer that the write be deferred until 
// the modified page writer has flushed some of the existing dirty data to disk.
//
// In order to assist the Cache Manager and the Virtual Memory Manager in 
// managing physical memory optimally, the file system driver can use 
// the CcCanIWrite() routine to determine whether the current write operation 
// should be allowed to proceed. Use of this routine is optional.
//
// The Wait argument allows the file system to specify whether the thread 
// can be blocked until the write can be allowed to proceed. If Wait is 
// FALSE and the write operation should be deferred, the routine returns FALSE.
// The file system can then determine an appropriate course of action - this 
// might be to postpone the operation using the CcDeferWrite() routine described 
// next in this section. Setting WAIT to TRUE causes the Cache Manager to block 
// the current thread (by putting it to sleep) until the write can be allowed 
// to proceed. Of course, the file system should ensure that no resources are 
// acquired by the thread since this may lead to a system deadlock.
//
// The Retrying argument allows a file system to notify the Cache Manager 
// whether permission is being requested (for the same write request) either 
// for the first time, or whether such permission had been requested (and 
// denied) at least once before. If set to TRUE, the Cache Manager assigns a 
// slightly higher priority to the current request while determining whether  
// it should be allowed to proceed or not (e.g. if two write requests are 
// pending and one of them is being retried, the Cache Manager will try its 
// best to allow the one being retried to proceed first. Note however, that 
// there are no guarantees to ensure that the one being retried will indeed 
// be allowed to proceed before the one not being retried).
//
// Conceptually, the functionality provided by the Cache Manager in this 
// routine is fairly simple and is as follows:
//
// - First, check whether the current write operation can proceed based 
// upon different criteria. These criteria include (among others): checking 
// whether the outstanding number of dirty pages associated with a file 
// stream have been exceeded, whether the total number of dirty pages 
// in the system cache have exceeded some limit, or whether the Virtual 
// Memory Manager might wish to block this write for some time until 
// enough unmodified pages are available in the system.
//
// - If the write operation can proceed, return TRUE.
//
// - Else, if Wait is set to TRUE, put the current thread to sleep until 
// the write operation can be allowed to proceed. Once the thread is woken 
// from the sleep, return TRUE. However, if Wait is FALSE, return FALSE 
// immediately.
//


typedef
VOID (*PCC_POST_DEFERRED_WRITE) (
        IN PVOID                                Context1,
        IN PVOID                                Context2
);

//
// CcDeferWrite()
//

VOID
CcDeferWrite (
        IN PFILE_OBJECT                         FileObject,
        IN PCC_POST_DEFERRED_WRITE              PostRoutine,
        IN PVOID                                Context1,
        IN PVOID                                Context2,
        IN ULONG                                BytesToWrite,
        IN BOOLEAN                              Retrying
);


//
// Resource Acquisition Constraints:
//
// No resources should be acquired before invoking this routine.
//
// Parameters:
//
// FileObject      Pointer to the file object structure representing 
//                 the open operation performed by the thread.
//
// PostRoutine     The routine to be invoked whenever it is appropriate 
//                 for the current write request to proceed. Typically, 
//                 this is a recursive call into the file system write 
//                 routine.
//
// Context1 & Context2   These are arguments that the PostRoutine will 
//                       accept (when invoked). Typically, if the post 
//                       routine is the same as the generic write routine, 
//                       these arguments are the DeviceObject and the Irp 
//                       (for the current request).
//
// BytesToWrite    Number of bytes being modified.
//
// Retrying        Allows the file system to specify whether the check 
//                 (should the write be allowed to proceed ?) is being 
//                 performed for the first time - or has already been 
//                 performed before.
//
// Functionality Provided:
//
// This routine is part of a group of routines that allow the file system 
// to defer executing a write request until it is appropriate to do so. 
// As discussed above, the CcCanIWrite() routine allows a file system driver 
// to query the Cache Manager whether the current write request should be 
// allowed to proceed immediately. If the CcCanIWrite() routine returns FALSE, 
// the file system can utilize the CcDeferWrite() routine to queue up the 
// write until it is appropriate for the write to proceed.
//
// The PostRoutine argument allows the file system to specify the routine 
// that will perform the actual write operation when invoked. It is quite 
// possible that the Cache Manager might chose to invoke the post routine 
// immediately (in the context of the thread invoking the CcDeferWrite() 
// routine). Typically however, the post routine is invoked asynchronously 
// whenever sufficient number of dirty pages have been flushed to disk and 
// the Cache Manager and Virtual Memory Manager feel more comfortable with 
// allowing the particular write operation to proceed.
//
```